# Running a .py file's function when function name and value passed to function defined in input prompt

Tags: python, function, input, command

I have a python file named `simple.py` and a function named `simple` in the same python file. The `simple` function takes the input of any integer value. The `simple` function divides the entered value by 2 and outputs the solution.

The problem statement or the challenge given to me is-
I need to prompt for an Input value in the format:

`simple.simple(34)`

First simple is the file name and the second simple is the function name.

This should call for a simple function in file simple.py and print the output value 17 (which is 34/2). I am struggling with the part where the function call is read from the input statement.

`def simple(number): solution=number/2 print("Output:\n") print("\t"+str(solution))`

Comment: Do you want to take this whole string `simple.simple(34)` as input from the prompt?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Can you Add your simple.py file?

Comment: added the file. somehow it is not take separate lines of the code.

Comment: Create a module named simple with a simple named function. Then in a different Python file (e.g. main.py) do import simple. From there you can run simple.simple(integer).

Comment: is it possible to run simple.simple(integer) from command prompt somehow? I am not allowed to create another file.

Comment: @ShraddhaAvasthy Are you trying to call python function from command prompt or are you trying to process input from stdin in python?

Comment: I was exploring command prompt as an option. I did a lot of reading over the weekend and I think that will be infeasible.